# Floating window without titlebar won't go to the top of the screen

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

My Mac app uses a floating window without a title bar that can be moved by dragging.

```
NSRect frame = NSMakeRect(500, 950, 600, 100);
        
self.lbWindow  = [[lbCustomWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:frame
                       styleMask:NSWindowStyleMaskBorderless
                       backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                       defer:NO];
        
[self.lbWindow setOpaque:NO];
[self.lbWindow setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
[self.lbWindow setHasShadow:YES];
[self.lbWindow setReleasedWhenClosed:FALSE];
```

However, this window can't be placed (eg created at that position), or moved (by dragging) to just under the top menu bar, it can only get to about 30px below it - it's exactly the height of a normal window title bar - basically, the window seems to be vertically constrained *as if* the window had a title bar.

(The Y co-ord "950" is the highest I can place the window, which results in the image below.)

[image: This is the highest the window can be placed or moved on screen]

I'd like this to act as though there was no title bar, and be able to place it so the top edge of the window is just below the menu bar.

(I haven't included the custom window implementation, but there's not much in there apart from dragging support - and it's not the dragging that's causing the constraint, as is still applies when you just initially position the window programatically.)

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just after posting I've found out why (typical). :)

The (transparent) window is created ok, but when I add the subview to it, for some reason (refactored old code) it's being added a title bar's height lower than the top of the window.

(It's obvious when you make the window non-transparent).

So just need to reposition the view and I should be fine.